# bad hour errors in crontab file, can't install

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I want my crontab to be every 4 hours but from a certain time 1 pm:

I chose this config:

```
0 1/4 * * *
```

but if I save I get the error:

```
bad hour errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

This following works perfectly, but then I cannot decide the starting time.

```
0 */4 * * *
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have `1/4` as the hours. This means "*run at 01:00 (1am), every 4 hours*". What you need is "*run from 01:00 (1am) until the end of the day, every 4 hours*".

```
0 1-23/4 * * *
```

You could also write this with the explicit hour numbers listed out, but I personally find this harder to process visually, and it's not so obvious that it means "*every four hours from 1am*":

```
0 1,5,9,13,17,21 * * *
```

Comment: Or `1,5,9,13,17,21`, since that's not terribly-more typing, and is straight-forward to visually parse.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think that depends on your PoV. I find `1-23/4` far easier to comprehend than having to read a list of numbers and realise that they're four-hourly.

Comment: Granted, given the expanded length -- it'd be easy to miss (e.g. 37) if it was absent; I'm a fan of computers doing the hard math :)